# Observable can't pass in finally from err state

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable, subscribe

Is not first time when I encounter this problem. Because I want to display some data on web page, even if the http request failed, I have some logique inside the `err` state. To not duplicate code in `subscribe` and `err`, I use to write it inside `complete`/`finally` state.

```
this.loadingResults = true;
this.service.get().subscribe(data => {
   // do something with the data
}, err => {
   this.initializeData();
}, () => {
   this.loadingResults = false;
   this.cd.detectChanges(); 
});
```

Because in the page I use a spinner how time I wait for the response, when it came (successfully or not, on `subscribe` or `err`), I want to change the `loadingResults` value to false and using `ChangeDetectorRef` to refresh the data on page.

The problem is that the above code will not work correctly and I need to renounce at `finally` function:

```
this.loadingResults = true;
this.service.get().subscribe(data => {
   // do something with the data
   this.loadingResults = false;
   this.cd.detectChanges(); 
}, err => {
   this.initializeData();
   this.loadingResults = false; // duplicate
   this.cd.detectChanges(); // duplicate
});
```

What's the best way to use finally and avoid repeat code in the rest of response types? I see its behavior is not like `try-catch-finally` from backend (Java/C#)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `subscribe` callbacks `error` and `complete` are mutually exclusive. One wouldn't be triggered if the other was triggered. Instead you could use the [`finalize`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/finalize) operator. It'll be triggered in case of completion or errors.

```js
this.loadingResults = true;
this.service.get().pipe(
  finalize(() => {
    this.loadingResults = false;
    this.cd.detectChanges(); 
  })
).subscribe(
  data => {
    // do something with the data
  }, 
  err => {
    this.initializeData();
  }
);
```

Also curiously, why are you triggering change detection manually? Whats stopping it from being triggered automatically?

Comment: I set `changeDetectionStrategy onPush` for the component because I have some children which use `onChange` lifecycle and don't want to be triggered for any event.

Comment: thx for answer. It works very well. Even I don't like to use `pipe` and one more operator, plus that the code seems to be upside down, is a solution :d